# PowerPoint API getSelectedDataAsync with coersion type SlideRange fails on new line character in slide title

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

This is more of a bug report for the PowerPoint API. (Office add-in)

When using getSelectedDataAsync with coersiontype SlideRange the request fails if there is a new line (\n) character in the title of the slide.
With failing I mean it is not giving an error or failed status, there is simply nothing returned and the callback function is never reached. This makes the rest of my code in the callback to not run.

What's the correct channel for reporting such a bug?

Changing the \n to \r in the slide title text seems to be working, but this is not an option as I can't know what the user enters in the slide title.

I would expect the new line characters to work in all scenarios, and the callback to be reached when doing the getSelectedDataAsync request.

Comment: This might help:  https://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/FAQ00992_Paragraph_endings_and_line_breaks.htm  Short version: PPT uses 0B or Chr$(11) in VBAspeak, for line and paragraph breaks in slide titles

Comment: Report bugs to https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose

Comment: @RickKirkham Reported, thanks for the link.